# Working with Collections-Maps

Tags: java, collections, maps

Am trying to gives more than one value to a key in a map. I wanted something of this kind to work..
mapp.put("key1","value1")
mapp.put("key1","value2").
The first value "value1" is getting over-ridden with "value2". How to retain both the values?  Should I go for any other thing than maps for this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use un map with list. Something like that:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

For put a `key1` with the first value:

```
if (!map.containsKey("key1")) {
    map.put("key1", new LinkedList<String>());
}
map.get("key1").add("value1");
```

For add the second value to `key1`

```
map.get("key1").add("value2");
```

You can have all this in one method

```
public void add(String key, String value) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
    }
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

If you want the values for the `key1`, you obtain a `List`

```
List<String> values = map.get("key1");
```

Answer (score 2):

Put both valyes into another collection (Vector, Set, Stack, whatever fits your usage; or anything else), and store hat collection as a value in a map.

As a random example using Vector:

```
Vector<Object> myVector = new Vector<Object>();
myVector.add("value1");
myVector.add("value2");
mapp.put("key1", myVector);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc of [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html),

**`A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.`**

So, if you want to put multiple values for single key, you need to add the values to the list and put key1 and list to the map.

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<K, HashSet<V>> map = new HashMap<K, HashSet<V>>();
if(!map.containsKey(k)) {
  map.put(k, new HashSet<V>());
}
map.get(k).add(v);
```

if you have duplicate values, use list/vector instead of hashset.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out a Multimap if you want a map with that behavior